# ZFDebug not rendering

Tags: debugging, zend-framework

Here's my application.ini,

`resources.Kco_Application_Resource_ZFDebug.enabled = true
resources.Kco_Application_Resource_ZFDebug.params.plugins[] = "Variables"
resources.Kco_Application_Resource_ZFDebug.params.plugins.File.base_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../"
resources.Kco_Application_Resource_ZFDebug.params.plugins[] = "Database"
resources.Kco_Application_Resource_ZFDebug.params.plugins[] = "Memory"
resources.Kco_Application_Resource_ZFDebug.params.plugins[] = "Time"
resources.Kco_Application_Resource_ZFDebug.params.plugins[] = "Registry"
resources.Kco_Application_Resource_ZFDebug.params.plugins[] = "Exception"`

And I'm using the Plugin from here:

http://www.phpriot.com/2420

Nothing is showing on the page, but the debug dump shows its being activated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pluginPaths.Kco_Application_Resource   = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/Kco/Application/Resource"

resources.zfdebug.enabled = false

resources.zfdebug.params.plugins[] = "Variables"
resources.zfdebug.params.plugins.File.base_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../"

resources.zfdebug.params.plugins[] = "Database"
resources.zfdebug.params.plugins[] = "Memory"

resources.zfdebug.params.plugins[] = "Time"

resources.zfdebug.params.plugins[] = "Registry"
resources.zfdebug.params.plugins[] = "Exception"`